# Пропадает сессионная cookie

Tags: php, cookie, сессия, codeigniter

Столкнулись со странной проблемой. У нас есть сайт, который может принимать платежи. Для осуществления платежа пользователь перенаправляется на сайт `Portmone.com`, где и осуществляет платеж. Перенаправление осуществляется с помощью специальной формы. После совершения операции, Портмоне перенаправляет пользователя обратно на указанный в форме `url` post-запросом. В параметрах передается статус операции и т.д. В большинстве случаев все происходит нормально, но иногда пользователь возвращается с пустыми куками, и, соответственно, сайт его не может опознать. Сессия слетает. Я до инициализации сессий логгирую состояние переменной `$_COOKIE`, и она оказывается просто пустой. Повторюсь, это случается не часто, может один раз из десяти. Я сам лично единожды это наблюдал, ничего особенного при этом я в браузере не делал.

Должен добавить, что Portmone - это не единственный агрегатор, с которым мы сотрудничаем, точно такая же проблема есть еще у одного агрегатора, так что я исключаю, что это их проблема.

По какой причине в принципе могут очищаться cookie? Сессионная кука `httponly`, ее из скриптов не почистишь.

Сайт работает на `php 7.4` + `codeigniter3`. Для аутентификации используется `ion_auth`

Comment: а точно ли дело в куках? точно ли они очищаются в браузере и запрос совершает именно он? может быть на сервере сессия истекает? как вариант можете передавать в backurl идентификатор пользователя, что бы не смотреть на куки, уж он то точно никуда не пропадёт

Comment: @Maximmka запрос совершает браузер, это точно. Я сам один раз наблюдал эту ситуацию. Если истекает сессия, куда деваются остальные куки? Там их обычно целый зоопарк от всяких гугланалитик и т.д. Передавать идентификатор можно, но хочется разобраться с проблемой.

Comment: может expiration короткий

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov Два часа. И опять же, куда остальные куки улетают? Не у всех же одновременно он заканчивается.

Comment: @Evgeny решили вопрос? Столкнулся с такой же проблемой

Comment: @Oleksandr нет. Переписал приложение так, чтобы не зависило от наличия сессионной куки